# Adding attribute filter sidebar in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, magento-core

Good morning,
I want to add a filter of attributes like this.[Like this](http://www.wheelup.it/it_it/caschi) I should put the attribute in static block first or how i can make it possible. Your answer will be very helpful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento already supports this out of the box.
It is called layered navigation. 
For category lists (where the categories are marked as "Is anchor" => 'Yes') and search results this happens automatically.
In order to have an attribute appear in the layered navigation, you need to mark it accordingly, by editing the attribute in the backend and setting the flag "Used in layered navigation" to "Yes".
but not all attribute types support this.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually i have seen a lot of your answers at this topic but a little bit difficult to understand. So, If i want to add advanced search on frontend how i can do it, Can you please explain me briefly. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SE. please don't mix questions. If this answer solved your problem, mark it as accepted. If you have other questions please ask them separately.

Comment: Thanks again, The attributes are showing in the sidebar but not as dropdown.